# Conditional probability formula in a profit function (exercise)

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Usually I have no problem solving simple problems in statistics, but in this one I feel like I´m missing something. It's a very simple problem:

> "A Newspapers' seller has a specific newspaper that costs him 70 cents and that he sells at 90 cents. If he does not sell a copy it has no value left and is destroyed at the end of the day. The seller considers that for each client that demands that newspaper and he doesn`t have a copy to sell he has a loss similar to 5 cents. The demand for the newspaper in a day can be represented as follows:
>
> Pr(demand=0) = .12
>   Pr(1) = .16
>   Pr(2) = .18
>   Pr(3) = .32
>   Pr(4) = .14
>   Pr(5) = .08
>
> If his profits depends only on the income from the newspapers he sells, the cost of newspapers he buys and the clients he loses, how many newspapers should he buy in order to maximize his profit?"

Thanks!

EDIT: What I did was to describe the profits as following:

$\pi = 90*S - 70*N - 5*LC$

Where:
$S$ = Sold Newspapers
$N$=Number Of Newspapers Bought
$LC$ = Number of Lost Clients.

Then I can use expectation and write:

$E(\pi ∣ N) = 90*E(S∣N) + 70*N - 5*E(LC∣N)$

But I can not find a formula for the conditional expectations.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you might mean by "missing something."  How are you thinking about this problem and what solutions have you attempted?

Comment: @whuber I have edited the post as an answer to you comment.  Sorry about the previous incompleteness.